# Running Thread Groups for Different Actions

Tags: jmeter, jmeter-plugins

I want to create test plan for `100` users with different action as:

> 1. Thread group 1 with 40 users as a. launch website b. search
> 2. Thread group 1 with 30 users as a. launch website b. login c. logout
> 3. Thread group 1 with 30 users as a. launch website b. Search c. add to cart

How can I create this test plan?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create this test plan in many ways by using different elements. The simplest way to do this:

- Add three thread group elements in your test plan and then define them accordingly.
- Under each thread group, you can add your user-specific requests/sampler (login, search, logout)

Your test plan should be like:

[image]

If you want to run those thread groups one at a time, check the "**Run Thread Groups consecutively**" settings in the Test Plan element.

Comment: I have created the same test plan but the problem is some requests are getting failed by giving error 500 Internal server error. and in one thread many samples are getting created Ex. for thread 1 more than 1 sample is run for login.